# Doctrine2 Composite key with foreign key - Embedded form issue

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

Let's take into account the following scenario.

I've got these entities

```
class RoomI18N
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="TextType")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="text_type_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $text_type;

    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Language")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="language_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $language;

    /**
     * @ORM\id
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Room", inversedBy="room_i18n")
     */
    protected $room;

    [...]
}
```

and

```
class Room
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    [...]

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="RoomI18N", mappedBy="room", cascade={"remove", "persist"})
     */
    protected $room_i18n;

    [...]
}
```

As you can see, `RoomI18N` entity have a composite key composed by three primary key of other tables (entities). This is a pretty common way to procede when you design a database and this will save also "space" as I don't need to store an extra field (id) that I don't need. Moreover data replication is the minimum and `RoomI18N` (composite) key will not be stored elsewhere into tables.

Said that, I'm in trouble as `RoomI18N` is the owning side of the relationship and I've created a form for `Room` entity where I can - or not - insert some textual informations for i18n.
When I bind the request to my form and persist a `Room` object, I receive back that error (* are placeded there on purpose)

> app.ERROR: Exception in *****: Entity of type ******\Entity\RoomI18N
>   is missing an assigned ID for field  'room'. The identifier generation
>   strategy for this entity requires the ID field to be populated before
>   EntityManager#persist() is called. If you want automatically generated
>   identifiers instead you need to adjust the metadata mapping
>   accordingly. [] []

Is pretty clear to me what's going on: doctrine try to persist `RoomI18N` objects *BEFORE* room object and, so, `Room` object still doesn't have an ID.

Ok, how can I escape from this situation if:

- I would prefer to avoid ID field as `RoomI18N` primary key
- I would prefer not to do some "strange" hack like: remove `RoomI18N` related object from Room object, persist it, place them again into original `Room` object and persist it again to DB

Moreover, of course, I've tryied to remove `cascade` hook and persist objects manually - just for try, I was sure that would not work - and of course nothing changed.

---

## Update

I controller I set all the `RoomI18N` as follows

```
$handled_languages = $lodging->getHandledLanguages();
[...]
foreach ($handled_languages as $language) {
    $room_text_i18n = new RoomI18N();
    $room_text_i18n->setLanguage($language);
    [...]
    $room->addRoomI18n($room_text_i18n); //fetched before
}
```

Comment: Does `Room::addRoomI18n()` also set the Room on the passed RoomI18N? Something like `public function addRoomI18N(RoomI18N $roomI18N) { $this->room_i18n->add($roomI18N); $roomI18N->setRoom($this); }`.

Comment: Ah, I see you've already figured it out :)

Comment: @JasperN.Brouwer: you were on the right direction, see my answer below

Comment: I would still advise you to have the `Room::addRoomI18n()` method take care of this. That way you can't forget it in other places (like controllers).

Comment: @JasperN.Brouwer: Yes, of course. I was only proposing the "quickest" solution based onto my question :) I've already done it into addRoom18n function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found the solution.
I need to *explicitly* set the inversed side object (`Room`) into owning side one (`RoomI18N`).

Basically I changed code of my controller as follows

```
$handled_languages = $lodging->getHandledLanguages();
[...]
foreach ($handled_languages as $language) {
    $room_text_i18n = new RoomI18N();
    $room_text_i18n->setLanguage($language);
    [...]
    $room->addRoomI18n($room_text_i18n); //fetched before
    $room_text_i18n->setRoom($room);
}
```

Hint came from: [enter link description here](http://www.doctrine-project.org/jira/browse/DDC-2244)

---

## UPDATE

As [Jasper](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1237411/jasper-n-brouwer) said, it will be better to modify `addRoomI18n()` function (`Room` entity, so inversed side) as follows

```
public function addRoomI18n(RoomI18N $roomI18n)
{
    $this->room_i18n[] = $roomI18n;
    $roomI18n->setRoom($this); //As is the owning side, I need to set it explicitly otherwise I need to set everytime 
                               //I want to persist a Room object

    return $this;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add instace of primary key entity instance while adding foreign key entity as following in primary entity..

```
 public function addRoomI18n(RoomI18n $RoomI18n)
        {
            $this->RoomI18n[] = $RoomI18n;
            $RoomI18n->setRoom($this);
            return $this;
        }
```

Comment: Yes, It's exactly what I've done, if you read comments (3 hours ago!!) you'll notice that snippet of code in my answer was written that way only because question is written that way, I wouldn't modify the whole thing but Jasper says the same of you and I agree. This question, to me, hasn't to be considerated and should be removed

Comment: Don't worry :) BTW I have updated my own answer. I suppose that now on it will be clear for all :)